# How does the “for” clause work in XQuery?

Tags: html, mysql, sql

I came across the problem when I was learning XQuery.
I don’t know how the “for” clause works in FLWOR expression.
How can the following XQuery perform join operation of `course`, `instructor` and `teaches` elements?
Is the variable in “for” such as `$c` a cursor-like stuff? 
I hope that someone can elaborate the work flow of the following XQuery and the function of the variables within the “for” clause.

```
for $c in /university/course,
    $i in /university/instructor,
    $t in /university/teaches[$c/course_id= $t/course_id and $t/IID = $i/IID]
return <course_instructor> { $c $i } </course_instructor>
```

[image: The “university” document (part 1)]

[image: The “university” document (part 2)]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xquery for loop questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839657/xquery-for-loop-questions)

Answer (score 0):

`for` is an iteration clause. It constructs a result based on the given query. Let's go through your code and see what it means..

`for $c in /university/course` executes its scoped line (whatever code comes under it..) for every element under `/university/course`. Same goes for `/university/instructor` and `/university/teaches`.

Without the filter for `teaches` as stated in `[$c/course_id= $t/course_id and $t/IID = $i/IID]` - you would essentially have a [CROSS JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) between `cource`, `instructor` and `teaches` that returns a multiplication of the three results.

Now - did I say cross join? Because you have *not* constructed your expected output yet, that must be confusing. In every join statement (if you know SQL a little bit...) [SELECT clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)) comes first (even though it might get processed at last..), unlike XQuery where you construct your logic - and then you decide what to return, as stated in `return <course instructor> { $c $i } </course instructor>`.

In your `return` statement, you are instructing XQuery that: for each record in the results returned by the cross join between the three results, `$c`, `$i` and `$t` - create a new `course instructor` element - and put `$c` and `$i` as its child elements.

*little note: element/attribute names cannot contain spaces. I'm not sure how "course instructor" would affect the outcome of your xquery. [Refer here for more info](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/07/25/namingparts.html)*

Comment: Thank you so much for your illustration.  I wonder that whether the **FLWOR** expression *actually* performs cross join or it just *performs* a cross join by a triply nested “for” loop which leads to the same effect. I know that in SQL, the **from** clause is executed first by computing the Cartesian product of the relations that follow the **from** keyword, then the **where** clause and other clauses are executed. So the **Select-From** query in SQL *actually* performs Cartesian product while the **FLWOR** doesn’t, even though their net effects are exactly the same.

Comment: I do not believe FLWOR "knows" what a cross join (or even a join..) is. So I would like to think the nested "for" loops lead it to perform the action and provide a somewhat similar result (not the same result.. one outputs a cursor to a record set, whilst the other results in a pointer to a DOM.. allegedly..)